# How to define a class just contains all constants variable?

Tags: dojo

How can i define a class just contains all constants variable? so late i can just refer my constants from any other classes like Constants.Car as a value("Blue Car") defined in Constatns class. let us say: Car = "Blue Car" in Constants class.

Answer (score 2):

I've been working with a slightly-over-engineered solution because I'm a little paranoid about:

1. Someone actually changing the constants by accident and screwing up a lot of stuff
2. Someone trying to access a nonexistent constant and not getting an obvious error

So the constant module looks like:

```
define(["dojo/_base/lang"], function(lang){

    // Variable is private, never directly exposed to outside world
    var constants  = {
        FOO : "alpha",
        BAR : "beta"
    };

    // If the name of a constant is given, return the associated variable.
    // If not, return all constants, but return a COPY so that potential
    // damage is limited.
    return function(cname){
        if(typeof cname == "undefined"){
            // Copy of our protected object
            return lang.clone(constants);
        }else{
            // Value of a particular thing            
            if(constants.hasOwnProperty(cname)){
                return constants[cname];
            }else{
                throw "Constant '"+cname+"' does not exist.";
            }
        }
    };

});
```

To use those constants, I go:

```
require(["package/my/constants"],function(myconstants){
    var x = myconstants("FOO"); // Should be "alpha"
    var y = myconstants(); // Should be {FOO:"alpha",BAR:"beta"}
}
```

Given that it's Javascript, there's probably a way to subvert this, but hopefully it is resistant against common mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

I would mimic what is done with `dojo/keys`

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/keys.html

Comment: Is there a better way to create a class then later refer it without to build a instance? Like: Constants.Car. without: theConstants = new Constants(); theConstants.Car;

Comment: You can always use the prortype to get to the property.  Constants.prototype.Car  But if you are not going to instantiate the class, then there is no need for the class.  Just use an object like dojo/keys